# How to draw in Game C#/C++ (Other application)

Tags: c#, graphics, draw

#### On my screen is what is inside the red square:

[image: http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/2319/xo3i.jpg]

#### I use this for draw in Game:

```
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    ...
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);
    ....
    IntPtr Hwnd = FindWindow("ClassName", "AppName");
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Hwnd);
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
    Point P1 = new Point(100, 400);
    Point P2 = new Point(1300, 400);
    g.DrawLine(myPen, P1, P2);
    g.Dispose();
```

#### But, the line is drawn inside the red rectangle:

[image]

[image]

#### My expectation was:

[image]

[image]

- Any questions related to question just say so.
- What I need to do what I want? What functions do I use?

Comment: Expected links work, actual ones don't .

Comment: @TonyHopkinson
Fixed!

Comment: Well you are getting the handle of what's on your screen, so if you want to draw something off screen to the left, coordinates would have to negative would they not?. However given the red square is a view pane, that may be harder than it sounds.

Comment: I want to draw in the game as well:
http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/6996/gnph.jpg
My screen should show this (Correct):
http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2628/wfbt.jpg
but, it shows this (Wrong):
http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/1415/fhxh.jpg

I do not want to draw on the screen, when the game is open, which is what my code does.

I want to draw inside the game, and not in the screen that I visualize.
Game size is: 5000x2500
My screen is 1366x768

Comment: Using an Window API only allows writing to what is visible on the screen and even then it will need to be redrawn on each screen update. Can you instead use a .NET Bitmap that you update and then display in a .NET form or control? (lots of examples out there doing it that way)

Comment: You can send me an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://bit.ly/19Vvor6

Comment: You can't draw out of the screen because there's nothing out of the screen. When you field of view changes to another area of the scenario, this part is rendered in the screen. To achieve what you want, you have to do a world to screen transformation which is gonna draw what you want in the game coordinates when the screen shows(render) it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a world to screen calculation in order to convert the world coordinates into screen coordinates. Every pixel in your screen (screen coordinates) has an equivalent x, y in world coordinates and this relation changes as you move your screen through the game scenario.

You want to make a draw starting at x = 100, y = 400 in world coordinates. If the center of your screen is at x, y and your screen resolution is 800x600, the code should be:

```
Point P1 = new Point(400, 300);
Point P2 = new Point(1600, 300);
g.DrawLine(myPen, P1, P2);
```